# PageFunction<List<string>> - how define in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

For PageFunction in xaml I wrote:

```
x:TypeArguments="sys:String"
```

But what if I need:

```
PageFunction<List<string>>
```

Really have to write a wrapper class? I hope that there is a simpler solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax :

*If the generic constraints themselves use generic types, the nested constraint type arguments can be contained by parentheses ().*

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:v4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
x:TypeArguments="generic:List(system:String)"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx

But that works only for loose XAML files, so **not in your case**, the v4 namespace being valid only for them :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/403b0e13-7772-4c70-a92e-4a87a891221c/issue-with-xtypearguments-generic-list-class-and-xaml

**You will have to subclass or use [System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection.aspx) instead :**

```
xmlns:specialized="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Specialized;assembly=System"
x:TypeArguments="specialized:StringCollection"
```

Comment: List<string> was an example. I need: `PageFunction<List<BookingLogic.Voyage>>`. How I understand - something like BookingLogic.VoyageCollection class will help me... Thanks for answer! (sorry for my English ;-))

Comment: public class VoyageCollection : List<BookingLogic.Voyage> {}